# Exec oracle.ucm.fa_client_ .jar in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle11g, jar

i want run in python and save response in var ,this is :

```
result=java -classpath "oracle.ucm.fa_client_11.1.1.jar" oracle.ucm.client.SearchTool 
-url=https://egjl.fs.us6.oraclecloud.com/_dav/cs/idcplg 
--username=myuser  --password=mypass  
--fields=dDocName,dOriginalName --defaultFields=false 
--dSecurityGroup="UCM_Spaces" --dOriginalName%=Assig%
```

i try to do  this:

```
import subprocess
result=subprocess.call(['java','-classpath','oracle.ucm.fa_client_11.1.1.jar','oracle.ucm.client.SearchTool -url=https://egjl.fs.us6.oraclecloud.com/_dav/cs/idcplg --username=myuser  --password=mypass --fields=dDocName,dOriginalName --defaultFields=false --dSecurityGroup="UCM_Spaces" --dOriginalName%=Assig%'])

Error: Could not find or load main class oracle.ucm.client.SearchTool -url=https:..egjl.fs.us6.oraclecloud.com._dav.cs.idcplg --username=myuser  --password=mypass --fields=dDocName,dOriginalName --defaultFields=false --dSecurityGroup="UCM_Spaces" --dOriginalName%=Assig%
```

Oh surprise !! : when i try in shell  work..

```
 java -classpath "oracle.ucm.fa_client_11.1.1.jar" oracle.ucm.client.SearchTool 
-url=https://egjl.fs.us6.oraclecloud.com/_dav/cs/idcplg 
--username=myuser  --password=mypass  
--fields=dDocName,dOriginalName --defaultFields=false 
--dSecurityGroup="UCM_Spaces" --dOriginalName%=Assig%
```

result:
dDocName       dOriginalName
UCMFA00123  Assig201903123

Answer (score 0):

Use python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html) to spawn a child process. It has all the tools necessary to read out what the child has written on stdout.

A simple way of getting the output is this:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
b'Hello World!\n'
```